# Error: Could not start Passenger Nginx core

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I am developing a website on RoR. Whenever I run `passenger start -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -d -e production` command on terminal, found an error

```
* ERROR *
Could not start Passenger Nginx core:
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open()
"/tmp/passenger-standalone.1rnha9m/logs/error.log" failed (2: No such file or
directory)
2013/09/16 07:52:21 [emerg] 12190#0: getgrnam("nogroup") failed
Stopping web server... done
```

Please any one could guide me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `could not open log file` is a red herring, which has been fixed last week. The *real* problem is this line here:

```
07:52:21 [emerg] 12190#0: getgrnam("nogroup")
```

It means that you're starting Passenger Standalone as a user whose group is `nogroup` (you're probably using the `nobody` user), but the `nogroup` group does not exist in the group database. Your group database is probably broken. Please fix this first.

Comment: We are staring the passenger at a root user.but still we have the same error. Please could you let us know where we fix it?

Comment: I used the following command: "groupadd nogroup" to resolve this on my Redhat 6 machine.